# How can concurrency per task be controlled for pcelery?

Tags: python, celery, pyramid

Can I have finer grain control over the number of celery workers running per task?  I'm running pyramid applications and using pceleryd for async.

from ini file:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('learning.workers.matrix_task',
                  'learning.workers.pipeline',
                  'learning.workers.classification_task',
                  'learning.workers.metric')
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 6
```

from learning.workers.matrix_task

```
from celery import Task
class BuildTrainingMatrixTask(Task):
 ....
class BuildTestMatrixTask(Task):
 ....
```

I want up to 6 BuildTestMatrixTask tasks running at a time.  But I want only 1 BuiltTrainingMatrixTask running at a time.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can send tasks to separate queues according to its type, i.e. BuildTrainingMatrixTask to first queue (let it be named as 'training_matrix') and BuildTestMatrixTask to second one (test_matrix). See [Routing Tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) for details. Then you should start a worker for each queue with desirable concurrency:

```
$ celery worker --queues 'test_matrix' --concurrency=6
$ celery worker --queues 'training_matrix' --concurrency=1
```